# How can i connect the filesystems of two docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-volume

so I have a static files (web app) running on container1, and a node js app that's running on container2, I want the node app the have writing access to the static files in container1. how can I achieve this?

what i tried so far :

- docker compose, but it only allow for communication between container (network access), not sharing the same filesystem. Therefore, node can't access files on C1.

Comment: Have you tried volume https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference?

Comment: You can mount same named volume to both containers.

Comment: @emix that's what i did, it worked! thank you

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is [docker-compose volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference)

An example configuration yaml file for **docker-compose v3** will be as below.

`/share` in host-os file system will be shared across these 2 containers

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  webapp:
    image: webapp:1.0
    volumes:
      - /share:/share
  nodeapp:
    image: nodeapp:1.0
    volumes:
      - /share:/share
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple HTTP server (a simple node one can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)) on one of the containers will allow you to host the static files. Then, this can be accessed from the other containers using the network all your containers are on.

Another option would be to mount a volume to both your containers. Any changes made via one container would reflect in the other if the same volume is mounted. More info can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).